# Creating Java arrays with the name of a variable

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am making a plugin for a Minecraft server and I need a way to store players in an array for the arena they are in. For example:

The plugin loads all the created arenas: `Arena1` `Arena2` `Arena3`

And I need it to create and array called `Arenas` and have an array inside that for each arena where I can store the player names so I know who is in which arena. I hope you get what I mean. I'll put it in a table format for you:

```
Arenas{
    Arena1{
        "Player1"
    }
    Arena2{

    }
    Arena3{

    }

}
```

I hope you understand and I hope you can help me. I know you guys are good

Comment: sounds like you need a multi-dimentional array {{Areana1},{Arean2}...}

Comment: You have lots of choices.  A 2-dimensional array is an obvious one.  Or you can have an array of lists (so different arenas can easily have different #/players).  Or an array of Maps (so you can easily search the list by player name).  Or a Map that contains a list of your Arenas. Etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

The programming concept you're after is known as an [Associative Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), the one most commonly used in Java is `java.util.HashMap`.  The names of arenas serve as keys, and they associate with the list of values.  So a simple example would be like:

```
Map<String, List<String> arenas = new HashMap<>();
//create player list for Arena1
arenas.put("Arena1", new ArrayList<String>());
//add a player
arenas.get("Arena1").add("player1");
```

Comment: Perfect, that is EXACTLY what I needed. This will save me sooo many problems. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A `Map<Arena, Set<Player>>` should do the trick nicely. Given an arena, it'll give you the set of players in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a `Map<String, List<String>>`

key is the name of the arena, in the list are the names of the players.

Comment: Yes, that's why MrSmith42 (and others) suggested a list.  Here's a good tutorial on Java collections: http://www.learn-java-tutorial.com/Collections.cfm#.UOdf0qxz3Kc

Answer (score 0):

Collections could be your solution:

```
class Arena {
  Set<Player> players = HashSet<Player>();
}
```

Then store them inside an `HashMap<String, Arena>` if you need to access them by name or `ArrayList<Arena>` if random access is enough.